# Hibernate is returning deleted rows

Tags: hibernate

I am using hibernate in my application to access database.
I am using this in a web server.
I am using houses table in database. A user can have more than house.
The problem is that when i am sending a request to the database to delete a house from the list of houses, it is deleting the house in the database.But i immediately reload the application to get the list of houses of user., Hibernate is still returning the house.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you call commit() on your session/transaction to cause the deletes to happen in the DB.

For example:

```
 Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();
 session.delete(houseToDelete);
 t.commit();
```